# What's wrong with this JSON object?

Tags: json

What's wrong with this?

```
{ 'z': 'hello' }
```

Looks like a valid JavaScript dictionary to me, but both Python JSON and http://pro.jsonlint.com/ are telling me

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    'z': 'hello'}
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give more details and code? How are you trying to use that JSON object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strings must be delimited by double quotes in JSON: http://www.json.org/

They can be single quoted in Python and JavaScript, but JSON is a very small subset of JavaScript.

Comment: Ah thanks. Should have thought of that. So used to js / python these days that I never even noticed.